# Can not find jndi datasource when deploying spring3+hibernate J2EE application to JBoss 6

Tags: hibernate, spring, jboss, datasource, jndi

I have a J2EE application which uses Spring 3.0 + latest version of Hibernate (3.6) and I want to deploy it on JBoss 6 CR1.

But I came across an exception stating that the datasource is not found when I deployed the application.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
 ... 159 more
```

I have checked the JMX console of JBoss Application Server and the datasource I declared in Spring is under java namespace.

I delcared the datasource in my application-context.xml as

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:ThisIsMyDataSource"/>
```

In persistence.xml file I declared:

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/ThisIsMyDataSource</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
```

A datasource with a name called ThisIsMyDataSource is in the deploy folder of /jboss/server/default/deploy

It looks like my application was trying to look for the bean for javax.sql.datasource to autowire into some other classes' constructors and failed.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a typo. Can you try with

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:/ThisIsMyDataSource"/>
```

instead of

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:ThisIsMyDataSource"/>
```